# Calculate run time of a cron

Tags: linux, curl, cron

I have a cron that is working fine but i want to calculate the execution time of the cron.

My cron looks like

```
0 */3 * * * root cd mydir && python myscript >> /var/log/mylog 2>&1 && curl https://nosnch.in/1837838u7184 &> /dev/null
```

I have tried this with no luck. I want to send the time to https://nosnch.in/blablabla

```
0 */3 * * * root m=`time(cd mydir && python myscript >> /var/log/mylog &> /dev/null) 2>&1` && curl -d "m=$m" https://nosnch.in/1837838u7184
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The `cd` shell builtin always has a very negligible time. So just measure the time of your python script.

```
 0 */3 * * * root cd mydir && time python myscript >> /var/log/mylog 2>&1 && curl https://nosnch.in/1837838u7184 &> /dev/null
```

Alternatively, make some shell script `$HOME/bin/myweirdscript` (containing both the `python myscript` & the `curl https://nosnch.in/1837838u7184` commands) and `time` it, so your `crontab` entry now becomes:

```
   0 */3 * * * root time $HOME/bin/myweirdscript
```

Comment: Not the solution I'm looking for. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I want to send the time to the url.

Comment: That should go into the question

Answer (score 0):

> I want to send the time to https://nosnch.in/blablabla

There is no *form* to post at https://nosnch.in/blablabla or https://nosnch.in/1837838u7184. Read the [cURL Manual](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html) section `POST (HTTP)`.